# Save the coordinates of a box with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

This is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/78/

As you can see, I have two boxes and they are draggable (using jsPlumb). I want to be able to save the positions they are in when I hit the "Save" button. I want the X and Y coords saved, how should I do this or approach this?

I want to store them, then post to the database in XML format (ie. x = 10, y = 10):

```
     <topY>10</topY>
     <leftX>10</leftX>
```

edit: took containment out

Comment: save which x and y coords? relative to parent element, relative document? Plus you are probably using the wrong containment element `jsPlumb.draggable("1",{ containment: "html" });` probably should be like `body` as right now your elements only move across the top of your fiddle.

Comment: it should be relative to document, right now i am populating them using the "top" and "left" in Style field

Answer (score 1):

For storing all the css properties of a element use the below code(iterate the code for all the elements and store them in an array which can be converted into JSON and sent to server for saving):

```
var str=$('#elem').attr("id") +","+ $('#elem').css("top") +","+ $('#elem').css("left") +","+ $('#elem').css("height") +","+ $('#elem').css("width");
```

Now the properties are stored in a single string seperated by "," . At the time of reusing split the string using:

```
var inf=str.split(",");
```

where inf[0] = id_value , inf[1] = top_value ,...., inf[4] = width_value.

Answer (score 0):

What you need seems like the `.offset()` function of jquery. It gives you the position of an element relative to the document.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get the position of mouse while dragging. little alterations might be needed on your end.

```
var top , left;
component.draggable({
  cursor: 'move',
  stop: function (event, ui) {
        top = ui.position.top;
        left =  ui.position.left;
  }
});
```

From here you'll get the position of an object so you can store that against save action.
Hope this will work for you.